AWS Amplify with Google Authentication: Compliance with App Store Guidelines for Privacy
I am currently implementing Google authentication using AWS Amplify in my React Native Expo app. I am using the following code:
await signInWithRedirect({
  provider: 'Google',
  options: {
    preferPrivateSession: true
  }
});

During the App Store review, my app was rejected due to the following guidelines:

Providing a login option that collects only the user's name and email address.
Offering an option for users to keep their email address private.
Ensuring that interactions within the app are not collected for advertising purposes without user consent.

I would like to seek advice on how to configure AWS Amplify and implement these requirements effectively. Specifically, I need guidance on how to:

Add an option for users to keep their email address private.
Ensure that interactions are not collected for advertising purposes without user consent.

In the Google Cloud consent screen settings, the following scopes are already enabled:

.../auth/userinfo.email - View the user's primary email address.
.../auth/userinfo.profile - View the user's personal information, including any personal info they've made publicly available.
openid - Associate you with your personal info on Google.
I have also attached a screenshot for reference: Simulator Screenshot.

Your guidance on how to meet these requirements with AWS Amplify would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
